# mvc3 rank zipcodes in uniform order

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-order-by

I have a database that contains over 10,000 U.S. zipcodes whats the best way to put these zipcodes in order? right now they are all shuffles around like : 10201,45089,32809 and I would like them to be in order from smallest to biggest like 10201,32809,45089 etc. They are under the field of "zip"

```
 var getinfo = sqlConnection.Query<zipcodes>("Select * from zipcodes ORDER BY zip DESC").ToList();
            foreach (var item in getinfo)
            {

                db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
```

Thats the code I have above and it is not ranking properly is there something else im missing? property zip is a float.

Answer (score 0):

Descending would put them from largest to smallest. What you want is to sort by ascending.
This can be done with linq:

```
 var sortedZipCodeList = getinfo.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
```

Id would be whatever property is in the zipcodes class that your trying to sort by.
(for descending order the syntax is:  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id))